# Remote entity relationship with Spring and JPA (hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, remoteobject, spring-remoting

I have 2 databases. The first one is the db of our company ERP and the second one the db of my app.

I need to working in my app with synched customers table data from ERP database. Now I synch the tables every hour with quartz job. In this way I have a local Customer table and I have no problem making a foreign key column in my Orders.

In future, developing new apps, this strategy will not be a good solution (assumed that it is now..). For every app, working in this manner, I will have local copy of customer table and a synching procedure..

So I'm thinking to implement a remote support application with spring-remoting with a remote interface in order to get customers. This remote application is connected to ERP database, and all my apps will call remote service to get data.

Now my questions is:

1. could it be a good approach or there are better way to implement
   this?
2. how to reference the Customer entity in my Orders? Following this solution I don't have local Customer table anymore.. I think I can do in domain class:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Order{

       ....

       private Integer customerId; 

       @Transient 
       private Customer customer;

       ...
   }
   ```

   and bind transient Customer every time I load Order object by
   calling remote service. So for example in my OrderServiceImpl

   ```
   @Transactional
   public Order getOrder(Integer id){
       Order order = orderDao.get(id);
       order.setCustomer(customerRemoteService.getCustomerById(order.getCustomerId()));
       return order;
   }
   ```

I wonder if you can give me comments or better solutions!

Thank you very much!!!!!
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access the ERP database directly, or so you have to go threw another app?

If you can access the database directly, you could use EclipseLink's Composite Persistence Unit support to map the entities to the multiple databases.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Composite_Persistence_Units

Comment: I think it's better for me suppose a scenario in which I can't access db directly.. And.. I'm using hibernate :-)